# Website graphics not appearing in certain browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

A site I'm working on doesn't appear to show certain graphics. For example using IE and firefox my site appears fine, however using Safari I get nothing but a blue background, the site in question is:

http://www.huntspillfederation.co.uk/

Doing it for a school and my web design skills are that great (as you can tell!)

I guess its the CSS thats the problem, in which case the error is somewhere in this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #background {
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        position: fixed; 
        left: 0px; 
        top: 0px; 
        z-index: -100; /* Ensure div tag stays behind content; -999 might work, too. */
    }
    .stretch {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .stretchw {
        width:100%;
    }
    #cloud1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        z-index:-99;
    }
    #cloud2 {
        position: absolute;
        right: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        z-index:-98;
    }
    .bottom {
    background-image: url("images/hill3.png");
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 263px;
    border: none; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index:-97;
    }

    body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    }
    h1 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family:Palatino Linotype;
    font-style:italic;
    }
</style>
```

Any help much appreciated!

:)

Comment: Have you tried modifying the CSS to determine what might be the cause?

Comment: I can see the hills in Safari 5.1.7 on a PC. The clouds are getting stretched though. That would be the percentages in the style attribute on the cloud images.

Comment: It looks like Safari is reading fixed position z-indecies differently from absolute. Your fixed-position background is appearing on top of all your absolute elements.

Comment: In the future, you should also put your code in a fiddle or some other website. That way when you change the code on your site, the code in question can remain for others who might have the same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your negative z-index's are the cause of the problem. Start at 0 and go higher for the elements that you want to appear in front of the background.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to use the container_bg1.jpg image in your background div. To your body tag, add:

   ```
   background-color: #67b8ed;
   ```

Then remove the background div and image.  You no longer need them at that point, and it's one less div and image to potentially conflict with everything else displayed on the page.

1. Don't apply a dynamic height and width to your images.  I see the clouds stretching based on the height of the window.
2. Images are appearing just fine to me in Safari, Chrome, IE and Firefox.